# Calculate Kendall's correlation in a python pandas dataframe with only one column of values

Tags: python, pandas

Assume the following dataframe format :

```
qualifier tenor date        return
AUD       1y    2008-04-14  0.0290
AUD       1y    2008-04-15  0.1205
AUD       1y    2008-04-16  0.1300
AUD       1y    2008-04-17  0.1488
AUD       1y    2008-04-18  0.1038
AUD       2y    2008-04-14 -0.00570
AUD       2y    2008-04-15  0.14080
AUD       2y    2008-04-16  0.05250
AUD       2y    2008-04-17  0.19120
AUD       2y    2008-04-18  0.20500
AUD       3y    2008-04-14 -0.00850
AUD       3y    2008-04-15  0.09980
AUD       3y    2008-04-16 -0.03850
AUD       3y    2008-04-17  0.11050
AUD       3y    2008-04-18  0.18000
```

Is there a way to calculate correlation between tenors (`tenor`) without using `pivot`, but by using `groupby(["qualifier","tenor"])`?

Comment: Can you show your expected output ?

Comment: can you write out a simple formula you are trying to replicate? like what are the inputs and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.groupby("qualifier").apply(lambda g: g.set_index(["date","tenor"]).unstack(level=1).corr())
```

it produces a correlation matrix between tenors for a given `qualifier`

```
            return
            tenor 1y        2y          3y
qualifier   tenor           
AUD return  1y  1.000000    0.668062    0.321667
            2y  0.668062    1.000000    0.915565
            3y  0.321667    0.915565    1.000000
```